# Require Framework suggestion for this mockup shown in the figure .

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dojo, yui

A very good day to all .
I was suppoused to develop a UI Mock as shown in the figure .

Could anybody please guide me what UI Framework is best suited for this kind of Requirement .

As you can see , ther is a Result display as well as Pagination suppourt required .

Choosing framework is currently my choice .

Thanks a lot .

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jQuery Flexigrid can be used for that.. http://flexigrid.info/

Answer (score -1):

I'd use jQuery:
[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

And this jQuery plugin:
[Datatables](http://datatables.net/)

And jQuery UI, themed to suit your mockup:
[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Answer (score -1):

Check [JQuery datatables](http://datatables.net/)